# Retrieving value from the onClickListener

Tags: java, android

so I got this onClickListener and inside of it i declare a value (int). Now my problem is thatI want to access that int outside of the onClickListener method. I know that onClickListener doesn't have a return value, but there has to be a work-around. What I am trying to is having the background change with each click and I use the integer to keep track of which color the background currently is
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
aa.setOnClickListener(new LinearLayout.OnClickListener(){
        int aaColor = 0;
        public void onClick(View v){
            switch (aaColor){
            case 0:
                aa.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
                aaColor++;
                break;
            case 1:
                aa.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
                aaColor++;
                break;
            case 2:
                aa.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                aaColor++;
                break;
            case 3:
                aa.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
                aaColor++;
                break;
            case 4:
                aa.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
                aaColor = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

So basically I want to store aaColor in another variable outside of this method. I use .png pictures as backgrounds but if there is a better way to keep track of the background, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing the point, but what prevents you from just declaring the variable outside the listener? Either declare it as a member variable of 'aa', or (cruder) globally in your class.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 solutions that I can come up with:

1) You can make the `aacolor` variable `static`.

2) You can have a `BackgroundManager.java` class which is a singleton and you can use its methods by calling `getInstance()`.

3) Lastly, if you define the `aacolor` variable inside a class definition but not in a method, it should be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use a singleton class. Get it's reference from any part of the code and make changes to it's attributes. I think of a singleton as a global "variable" :)
On this [link](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/designpatterns/index.html) you can find a well made example (at the bottom), just copy that into your code and you're ok.

Answer (score -1):

You can user a SharedPrefences

```
aa.setOnClickListener(new LinearLayout.OnClickListener(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        int aaColor = 0;
        public void onClick(View v){
            switch (aaColor){
            case 0:
                aa.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
                editor.putInt("BgColor", aaColor).commit();
                aaColor++;
                break;
            case 1:
                aa.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
                editor.putInt("BgColor", aaColor).commit();
                aaColor++;
                break;
            case 2:
                aa.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                editor.putInt("BgColor", aaColor).commit();
                aaColor++;
                break;
            case 3:
                aa.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey);
                editor.putInt("BgColor", aaColor).commit();
                aaColor++;
                break;
            case 4:
                aa.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
                editor.putInt("BgColor", aaColor).commit();
                aaColor = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```